# Convert office document to PDF with horizontal page in the middle

Tags: pdf, microsoft-office, print-to-pdf, cutepdf

I'm using [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/) to convert a Word Document to PDF, but the document has one page in the middle with a horizontal page layout and the PDF doesn't get the horizontal page. Is there a way / tool I can use so I can get the PDF as I'd want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Office 2007, update to SP2. Under the "Save As" submenu you will find "PDF or XPS". It works really good.

Comment: ...or download the 'Save as PDF or XPS' add-in from: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041&displaylang=en

Comment: Downloaded the add-in while waiting for the SP2 update. Thank you both :)