# Split Word/PDF files into multiple documents?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word

I created a business card design on Word, each side of the card as one 85x55mm page. Most printers seem to want it in PDF file which is easy, but they sometimes want each side as a different document.

Is it possible to split a word or PDF file into multiple documents, e.g split on a page-break? I can't find an option in Word 2007 and no idea about Acrobat but I doubt it.

Comment: @John: superuser.com is a better site for non-programming, but still computer and software related questions.  You can get information on joining the semi-private beta on the SO blog. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PDF Split and Merge](http://www.pdfsam.org/).

Comment: +1 recommended this to one of our clients and it seemed to do the job rather well.

Comment: @arathorn - whilst this does answer the question, it would be a lot better if you could explain exactly *how* to use this tool to split PDF files

Answer (score 6):

If using the commandline is an option, I would recommend [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/).

`pdftk multipage.pdf burst`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Office 2007, you can install this [Microsoft Add-in](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041&displaylang=en) for converting to PDF, or update to Office 2007 SP2 that has this add-in included, as said [here](https://superuser.com/questions/19231/convert-office-document-to-pdf-with-horizontal-page-in-the-middle/19274#19274).

Answer (score 0):

You can split pages from a PDF into individual documents using Acrobat.

Comment: A little more detail, like a hint of which menu to look at, would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a free program like [doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/) and print page 1 to a PDF, then print page 2 to a separate PDF.